# How to declare Mat that stores float values between 0 and 1 in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to compare the values of a Mat with RBG image (i.e. Mat with 3 channels) with a threshold `Mat th = [0.2,0.2,0.2]` where each value in Mat th corresponds to threshold for each channel i.e. `th=[th for Red,th for blue,th for Green]`.

When I declare th as `Mat th(3,1,CV_32F,Scalar(0.2,0.2,0.2));`
The output of `cout<<th;` shows `th=[0,0,0]`. What mistake am I doing in declaring the datatype?
And for 3 channels, do I need to declare it as `Mat th(1,1,CV_32UC3,Scalar(0.2,0.2,0.2))`?
Which data type helps to capture the logic for 3 channels and non-integer numbers ?

Comment: It looks like your question is incomplete.

Comment: The lower part doesnt get submitted , so had to submit it as a code portion. I hope the question is legible ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for CV_32FC3. Another option would be to use Vec3f if you only want a single pixel.

```
Mat th(1,1,CV_32FC3,Scalar(0.2,0.2,0.2));
```

or

```
Vec3f th(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use type **`CV_32FC3`** or **`CV_64FC3`** for float in 3-channel `Mat`.

---

```
Mat th(3,1,CV_32FC3,Scalar(0.2,0.2,0.2));
```

or

```
Mat th(3,1,CV_64FC3,Scalar(0.2,0.2,0.2));
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, but i think i should modify it as th(1,1,CV_64FC3,Scalar(0.2,0.2,0.2)) because I only need one value of each channel . Thank you !